# In emacs what does the first letter after the Meta key stand for?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

In emacs what does the first letter after the Meta key stand for? 
I am guessing these are specific groups but I don't know what they are:

So here is what I have seen and my best guesses
Please correct these if I am wrong.

M-x  --> "looks like x for execution"
M-m
M-s
M-t  --> "looks like t for transpose"

Thanks

Comment: If those mnemonics work for you, then fine, go ahead and use them in your head. Your guess is probably correct, since `M-x` runs the command `execute-extended-command`, and `M-t` runs `transpose-words`, but the only way to know for sure what the designer/developer had in mind when he chose those bindings would be to go back and scan his brain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general rule here.

You can get more info about keys available by doing M-x describe-prefix-bindings. Try searching the resulting buffer for lines that start with the literal characters M- to see the various sets of commands that are available. Some have mnemonics that make sense like M-s for search and M-g for goto, other's its harder to divine why that key was chosen like M-o for face related commands.

Comment: He's not asking about the difference between `Meta` and `Ctrl`, but about the meaning of the following mnemonic character.

Comment: Correct the meaning of the mnemonic character so I could possibly remember these key combinations better. But I guess with time muscle memory will kick in! :)